# Turning bars to a normal distribution

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn

I'm new to python .

I have 2 arrays, and a nice bars graph :

```
# Buyers in %
h =[1,1,3,5,9,13,16,16,14,10,5,4,2,1,0]

# Clothes size
x =  [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48]

# P(X=40) =  16 % // The probability that some buyers gets a 40 sized clothe is 16 %
# P(37 <= X <= 40)  = 5+9+13+16 = 43 % // The probability that somes buyers gets between 37 and 40 sized clothes is 43 %

plt.ylabel('Buyers % ')
plt.xlabel('Clothes Size')
plt.bar(x, height = h)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

1. How could I turn that to a density line and a normal distribution using seaborn or [scipy.stats.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy-stats-norm) and draw it over the bars ?
2. After that , How could I calculate P(X<40) using the normal distribution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using seaborn:

```py
# Buyers in %
h =[1,1,3,5,9,13,16,16,14,10,5,4,2,1,0]

# Clothes size
x =  [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48]
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
data = []
for i in range(len(x)): data += [x[i]]*h[i] 
sns.set()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5),dpi=300)
sns.distplot(data, fit=norm, kde=False)
```

[image: resulting plot]

To get the probability:

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
sample = data
sample_mean = np.array(data).mean()
sample_std = np.array(data).std()
min_value = int(sample_mean-4*sample_std)
max_value = int(sample_mean+4*sample_std)
dist = norm(sample_mean, sample_std)
values = [value for value in range(min_value, max_value)]
probabilities = [dist.pdf(value) for value in values]

#plt.plot(values,probabilities)

def prob(min_lim,max_lim):
    p = (np.array(values)>min_lim).astype(int)* (np.array(values)<max_lim).astype(int)
    prob = (np.array(probabilities)[p.astype(bool)]).sum()
    return prob

prob(0,40)

Out[2]: 0.3230891372830226
```

NOTE: it's different from the calculated one because it's using a continuous estimated normal distribution from the mean and standard deviation of your data.

If you don't want to use the continuous estimation, the code is just:

```
len(np.array(data)[np.array(data)<40])/len(data)
Out[2]: 0.32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try out this